# search for more than one object in AD using DirectorySearcher

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need to search for OU info and the Users, groups, pcs of that OU, I can search for them individually but I want to know if I can make it in the same function.
this is my code for ou

```
DirectoryEntry st = new Directoryentry("xxx","xxx","xxx");
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(st);
search.filter("objectCategory=organizationalUnit");
foreach(searchresult s in search.FindAll())
{
    if(s.path.contains("ou name")){
    Console.WriteLine(s.path);
    }
}

Can I do something like:
        search.filter("objectCategory=organizationalUnit")("objectCAtegory=user");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search for multiple specific entry types, you'd do something like...

```
search.Filter("(&(objectclass=organizationalUnit)(objectclass=user))")
```

If you want to search for everything you could just use...

```
search.Filter("(objectclass=*)")
```

Check out the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks that helped but now I have another problem, Im trying this filter but it wont work.     `code`(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=Employees,OU=Security Groups,DC=yourdomain,DC=com))`code`

Comment: Are you trying to get the members of a group?  If so, you'd be better served by getting the DE of the Group and enumerating the "members" property.

Comment: thank you very much for your time, I can not thank you enough

Comment: Hi Christian BP, you seem to be very knowledgeable in about the DirectorySearch object.  Should this code be correct to return the user that matches on SAMAccountName and department?               DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
                    ds.Filter = "(&(SAMAccountName=" + userName + ")(department=Information Technology))";

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant to ask codingChris, you seem to be very knowledgeable about the DirectorySearch object.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and that's what I thought.  For some reason it isn't working and is blocking members of the department, very odd.

Comment: Actually, nevermind it does work correctly...thanks again codingChris!